# How to copy one class object to another class object using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have created two classes like below

```
class Person: NSObject {

var ID : String?
var firstName : String?
var lastName : String?

override init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience required init?(personID : String, firstNameValue : String, lastNameValue : String) {
    self.init()
    self.ID = personID
    self.firstName = firstNameValue
    self.lastName = lastNameValue
}}
```

and

```
class ListItem: NSObject {

var ID : String?
var value : String?

override init() {
    super.init()
}

convenience required init?(itemID : String, itemValue : String) {
    self.init()
    self.ID = itemID
    self.value = itemValue
}}
```

Now in my viewController class I have an array of Person class and want to convert it into an array of ListItem class.
Anybody please tell me how can I do this using Swift.

Comment: What is the connection between this two classes ?

Comment: What exactly do you meant by convert Person to ListItem? They have nothing in common???

Comment: I want to use array of ListItem class as datasource into UITableView delegates while my webservice return data as list of Person class.

Comment: @user3305573 Are you getting response as JSON like Person class or Person Object?

Comment: Why do you use optional properties but non-optional init parameters and why do you use failable initializers which practically can and will never fail?

Comment: what is the value here???
 var value : String

Comment: @NiravD Yes I am getting response in JSON then I parse the JSON in Person class by using Object Mapper library

Comment: @user3305573 Have you try simpleBob answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can map one type of objects into another with [flatMap](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1687661-flatmap), like this:

```
let listItemList = personList.flatMap({ ListItem(itemID: $0.ID ?? "unknown", itemValue: "\($0.firstName ?? "") \($0.lastName ?? "")")})
```